# How to debug JavaScript tests in JHipster applications using Karma?

Tags: karma-runner, jhipster

I have a simple monolithic application generated using JHipster v4.10.1 with front-end using Angular 4.x. To run JavaScript unit tests, as suggested in [the documentation](http://www.jhipster.tech/running-tests/) I ran

`./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js --debug`

The command runs the tests, reports coverage summary and exits, whether tests all pass or some test fail does not matter. Test run output does show at one point that the debug server is loaded:

`21 11 2017 13:41:20.616:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/`

But because the command exits, the [Karma debug server](http://localhost:9876/debug.html) can not be accessed. How to run tests so that Karma console can be used in browser to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the magic flag is actually `single-run` which seems to be true by default. So the main command to run for JS debug is:

`yarn test --single-run=false`

which in turn runs

`$ karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js --single-run=false`

With this the command will only exit with explicit kill e.g. with Ctrl+C or Z. Karma debug console can then be accessed on  `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` (assuming default port is not already busy. If it is, test output should tell you which port was chosen).

Additionally you need to disable minimization (and also istanbul config - not sure why) so that you can breakpoint and step through the .ts code in debugger easily. I figured this is done by making following changes in `webpack/webpack.test.js` file:

Remove following istanbul config from `module.rules` array:

```
        {
            test: /src[/|\\]main[/|\\]webapp[/|\\].+\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'post',
            exclude: /(test|node_modules)/,
            loader: 'sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader?force-sourcemap=true'
        }
```

Add `minimize: false` to the `LoaderOptionsPlugin` under plugins array:

```
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: false,
        options: {
            tslint: {
                emitErrors: !WATCH,
                failOnHint: false
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Another easier alternative is to simply run `yarn test:watch` This will also watch changes to test specs and re-run.